# How do you make an array of lists from seperate arrays then find most frequent value per lists with python?

Tags: arrays, loops, python-2.7, numpy

If there are the below three arrays:

```
array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.])
array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

And I want to combine the arrays into an array of list of each element then find the **mode (most frequent value)** of each lists like the example below:

Step 1)    `array([0., 0., 1.], [1., 1., 0.], [1., 0., 1.], [1., 1., 1.], [0., 1., 1.])`

Step 2) `array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1.])`

How could this be done in Python?

Comment: Do you have `scipy` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.stats.mode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html):

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> a = np.array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
>>> b = np.array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.])
>>> c = np.array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> m = np.vstack([a,b,c])
>>> modes, counts = scipy.stats.mode(m)
>>> 
>>> modes
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

and then call `.squeeze()` or `.ravel()` if you want to get back to a 1-D object.